# Add dot to text in blazor server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a variable in a razor page. I want to display this variable and add some static text at the end. I do not want to change the variable content.

```
@{
  var str1="test";
}
...
@if (condition)
{
    @str1...
}
```

Here is what i want to display:

> test...

How can i print the 3 dots ?
At this step, i get a compiler error because the first dot may be intepreted as C# code... I have also tried to put the dots in a span tag but it is very verbose.

Comment: Your existing code will work if you enclosed the parameter in markup like:  <span>@str1...</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@if (true)
{

    @($"{str1}...")
}
```